# Overriding code in memory securely

Tags: c++, windows, memory, locking, hook

I have a DLL that I am loading into a process. The purpose of the DLL is to hook some Windows APIs by placing a jmp on top of the function to my handler. I'm just wondering can I just patch the function like this:

```
*pFunction = 0xE9 //jmp 
*(pFunction+1) = &HookHandler
```

Or should I kind of lock the memory region first, so that the process can't call the function while I am patching it?

Comment: Locking the memory region will not prevent the process from calling it, it will just ensure that if the process will raise an exception if it does.

Comment: Which admittedly may be a wiser solution than corrupting your IP

Comment: actually what i have worked out is: 1) suspend all threads 2) patch function 3) resume all threads and fixx EIP for those threads that point to the patched function